# Connection string error

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic, connection-string, adodb

Having a problem with IIS on Windows Server 2003 (using a classic ASP web application)
The database server (SQL Server 2005) is on the same machine.

I create a recordset, and set its activeconnection as follows:

```
Dim RS
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;"
```

The problem is that as SOON as I set this connection string, the following error is raised:

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

I know there isnt a problem with this connection string because when I use my development server, but point the connection toward the remote database, it works great.

I have tried many MANY connection string variations (from connectionstrings.com) and they have given the same error.

Comment: try to create an .udl file in your production server and build that connection string there; maybe you have some different package installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RobV - Creating a connection object and assigning that to the recordset is indeed an option, however, a shortcut to this is assigning a connection string to the recordset - which does work.

In fact the following code is the most efficient:

```
Dim RS
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open <sqlstatement>, <connectionstring>
```

Im not sure what happened with the error I was getting but it SUDDENLY just stopped without having changed any code!

Comment: If you're only doing one database call then yes, doing it that way may be succinct but you'll be creating a database connection for each recordset you open which is not very efficient - from MSDN "However, if you are opening multiple Recordset objects over the same connection, you should explicitly create and open a Connection object; this assigns the Connection object to an object variable. If you do not use this object variable when opening your Recordset objects, ADO creates a new Connection object for each new Recordset, even if you pass the same connection string."

Comment: But yes you are write that you can set the ActiveConnection as a String

Comment: Legend - this could well explain why i was getting the timeout error (caused by the MSDE workload governor when 5 connections is exceeded) - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveConnection` property takes an Object of type `ADODB.Connection` and not a String.  You can't assign a Connection String directly, you need to assign a database connection.  Your code needs to look like the following:

```
Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
objDB.Open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;"
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.ActiveConnection = objDB
```

Actually you shouldn't really use the `ActiveConnection` property in this way at all, what you should actually use it for is disconnecting a recordset to avoid keeping the database connection open unecessarily:

```
Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
objDB.Open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;"

//Get a Recordset and prep it for forward only disconnected use
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRS.CursorType = adOpenStatic
objRS.LockType = adLockReadOnly
objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE", objDB

//Now disconnect the recordset and dispose of the database connection
Set objRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
objDB.Close
Set objDB = Nothing

//Now do whatever you want with the Recordset
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something similar to this [MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675960(VS.85).aspx).

It's creating a connection separately, then assigning it.